# Создание псевдоэлемента при наведении курсора

Tags: css

Подскажите, как правильно выводить псевдоэлемент after при наведении курсора на элемент: создавать after непосредственно при наведении, или создать after до наведения курсора на элемент и скрыть его, а потом, при наведении показать псевдоэлемент?
т.е. нужно ли создавать псевдоэлемент до наведения курсора?
https://jsfiddle.net/tp0tuaf7/

```
<a href="#">link </a>
```

css

```
a:hover:after{
  content: ' hover';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

в этом коде получается что after ещё не существует в dom до наведения курсора. Или нужно сначала создать after скрытым, а потом показать?
подскажите как правильно нужно создавать after, и как это будет влиять на производительность если создавать при наведении?

Comment: Без разницы вообще

Comment: @Рашен Беар, откуда такие сведения?  А если вместо текста в псевдоэлементе будет какое-то большое изображение или какой-то объект?